# Troubles with the CGAL library Vertex_visibility_graph_2.h

Tags: c++, graph, visibility, cgal

I'm having troubles with the CGAL library **Vertex_visibility_graph_2.h**, for visibility graphs.
The code I'm trying is like the following:

```c
    typedef CGAL::Cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq> Kernel;
    typedef CGAL::Arr_segment_traits_2<Kernel> Traits_2;
    typedef CGAL::Vertex_visibility_graph_2<Traits_2> Vis_graph;  
    typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<Kernel> Polygon_2;

    Vis_graph graph(polygon.vertices_begin(), polygon.vertices_end());
```

But when I try to compile, I get the error:

```
/opt/local/include/CGAL/Partition_2/Vertex_visibility_graph_2_impl.h:528:30: error: 
      no matching function for call to object of type 'Intersect_2' (aka
      'CGAL::Arr_segment_traits_2<CGAL::Cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>>::Intersect_2')
```

Has anybody used that library before?

Comment: Strange that you define `Kernel` as `Cartesian<double>` while the error mentions `Cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>`.  It might well be a bug in CGAL with `Partition_2` using an old interface of `Intersect_2`.  I'd recommend posting this on the cgal-discuss list to get the maintainers attention.

Comment: Actually, it was my bad. I copied and pasted before changing types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace:
`typedef CGAL::Vertex_visibility_graph_2<Traits_2> Vis_graph;`
by
`typedef CGAL::Vertex_visibility_graph_2<Kernel> Vis_graph;`